awk to remove trailing commas
I am trying to use awk to remove trailing commas from in.csv from each line. The awk below does execute but prints all entries on one line.
in.csv:
gene,transcript,cNomen,pNomen,Genomic Description,,,,,,
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1773C>A,p.Y591*,chr20:31022288C>A,,,,,,
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1954G>A,p.G652S,chr20:31022469G>A,,,,,,

Desired:
gene,transcript,cNomen,pNomen,Genomic Description
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1773C>A,p.Y591*,chr20:31022288C>A
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1954G>A,p.G652S,chr20:31022469G>A

Code:
 awk -F',' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i != "") { printf("%s", $i) }
    if (i<NF) printf(",")
} 
printf("\n") }' in.csv


Why not just sed 's/,*$//'?

Your code does not do what you claim; it simply prints the contents unmodified. Demo: https://ideone.com/N82Ect

Is fixing the tool that generates the original CSV so it doesn't add a bunch of trailing ,s not an option?

Why not just
awk '{ sub(/,+$/, "")} 1' in.csv

or equivalently
sed 's/,*$//' in.csv

The flaw with your attempt is that it would still print the comma even if a field was empty. Also, if you fixed that, it would obliterate empty fields from the middle of a line, not just from the end.
Here's a different approach which attempts to preserve the basic idea of your code:
awk -F , '{ for (i=NF; i>0; i--)
    if ($i != "") { nf=i; break }
  for(i=1; i<nf; ++i) printf "%s,", $i
  print $nf }'

We loop backwards from the last field until we find a non-empty one, then print the fields up through that one, with a comma after each except the last, which is then printed with a newline instead after the second for loop.
Demo: https://ideone.com/U5joBb
If you are confident that empty fields can only occur at the end, then maybe
awk -F , '{ sep="";
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i == "") break;
    printf "%s%s", sep, $i;
    sep=FS }
  print "" }'

Notice how we print the separator before the next field, and start with an empty separator; that way, we avoid printing a comma after the last non-empty field, whilst keeping the rest of the code uniform.
(The earlier script could use the same logic as well; I wanted to show some common variations.)
Demo: https://ideone.com/XPGQUZ

You might get n first fields in GNU AWK by setting NF to that value. Let file.csv content be
gene,transcript,cNomen,pNomen,Genomic Description,,,,,,
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1773C>A,p.Y591*,chr20:31022288C>A,,,,,,
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1954G>A,p.G652S,chr20:31022469G>A,,,,,,

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{NF=5;print}' file.csv

gives output
gene,transcript,cNomen,pNomen,Genomic Description
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1773C>A,p.Y591*,chr20:31022288C>A
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1954G>A,p.G652S,chr20:31022469G>A

Keep in mind this solution assumes you know apriori number of columns to get.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

You could adapt my middle script to set NF=i before the break, and then just print the whole (remaining) line unconditionally.

awk ~ RS=',*\n'


gene,transcript,cNomen,pNomen,Genomic Description
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1773C>A,p.Y591*,chr20:31022288C>A
ASXL1,NM_015338.5,c.1954G>A,p.G652S,chr20:31022469G>A

End to end, the awk solution is only 2 bytes more than sed :
awk ~ RS=',*\n'
sed 's/,*$//'

